# Replace letters with integer and place "-" (dash) with it

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently using the following JavaScript code:

```
concatedSubstring.replace(/\//g, '-').replace(/[A-Za-z]/g, function(c){
    return c.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)-64; 
});
```

...to take input in the format `"1234/A"`, `"22/B"`, etc. and output `"1234-1"` , `"22-2"`, etc.

That is, `/` becomes `-`, and the letters become integers with A = 1, B = 2, etc.

I would like to change this so that if the input doesn't contain a "/" the output will still insert a "-" in the spot where the "/" should've been. That is, the input `"1234A"` should output `"1234-1"`, or `"22B"` should output `"22-2"`, etc.

Comment: So "1234B" should turn into "1234-2" (your question has "1234-1")?

Comment: sorry my mistake 1234B must be replaced with 1234-2

Comment: Do you know what the word *alphabet* means in English?  Not the way you’re using it.  There are things like the Latin alphabet, the Greek alphabet, the Phoenician alphabet, etc.

Comment: Tho grammatically you are correct I should be using word letter but at that moment the 1st thing that popped to my mind was alphabet, As English isn't my native language. But I think my question explains what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work even for inputs containing more than one of your number/letter pattern:

```
var input = "1234/B 123a 535d";

var replaced = input.replace(/(\d+)(\/?)([A-Za-z])/g, function(m,p1,p2,p3) {
   return p1 + "-" + (p3.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)-64);
});

alert(replaced); // "1234-2 123-1 535-4"
```

The regex:

```
/(\d+)(\/?)([A-Za-z])/g
```

...will match one or more digits followed by an optional forward slash followed by a single letter, capturing each of those parts for later use.

If you [pass a callback to `.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) then it will be called with arguments for the full match (which I'm ignoring for your requirement) and also for any sub-matches (which I use).

Answer (score 2):

`str = "1234/B"; or str = "1234B";`

str.replace(/(\/[A-Z])|([A-Z])/g,"-"+parseInt(str.charCodeAt(str.indexOf(str.match(/[A-Z]/g)))-64))

Comment: Doesn't this do what the code in the question already does? OP wants to insert a hyphen even when there isn't a forward slash, on input like "1234B".

Comment: str = "1234B";

str.replace(/(\/[A-z])|([A-z])/g,"-"+parseInt(str.charCodeAt(str.indexOf(str.match(/[A-z]/gi)))-64))

Comment: Note also the range `A-z` includes some non-alphabet characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can also `.replace(/([0-9])([a-zA-Z])/g,"$1-$2")`: this turns a number adjacent to a letter into numberDASHletter, using backreferences (the `$1` refers to whatever was in the first set of brackets, `$2` to whatever was in the second set of brackets).